# Error "Function call on left side of assignment must return Variant or Object"

Tags: string, function, vb6, return

So here is a code snippet. The error I am getting is "Function call on left side of assignment must return Variant or Object". I changed the function return to a variant data type, but that did not help.

I am trying to generate a random string using function calls. Because it is a large number of sub tables I want to maintain the tables separated like so instead of in a single long series of code for ease of maintainability.

If this is not viable, can anyone suggest an alternative method of doing this?

```
Private Function GenAstStrategicResouce() As Variant

    Dim X As Integer

    X = Int((200 * Rnd) + 1)

    If X < 10 Then
        GenStrategicResouce = "Bose-Einstein Condensates"
    ElseIf X < 20 Then
        GenStrategicResouce = "Diamonds"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: It's `Function GenAstStrategicResouce`, but you're making assignments to `GenStrategicResouce`. Put `Option Explicit` at the start of the module to help catch mistakes like that.

Comment: What's a "resouce" anyway?  Point being, typos are a killer.  I agree that `Option Explicit` can help but maybe you need to raise your monitor's DPI settings.  That reminds me, I need to get new glasses myself.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the function to return a string.

You also have mistyped the function's name on the return as GenStrategicResouce  instead of GenAstStrategicResouce.

```
Private Function GenAstStrategicResouce() As STRING

    Dim X As long

    X = Int((200 * Rnd) + 1)

    If X < 10 Then
        GenAstStrategicResouce = "Bose-Einstein Condensates"
    ElseIf X < 20 Then
        GenAstStrategicResouce = "Diamonds"
    End If

End Function
```

It cannot return anything else so a variant (typically used to possibly return a CVErr or array) is unnecessary.

Comment: Also, remember to call `Randomize()` before you _first_ use `Rnd` in order to initially seed the random number generator, otherwise, the result won't _actually_ be random.